# Angular/PrimeNG How to fill text field programmatically

Tags: angular, primeng

I am trying to programmatically set the text of  the auto complete field how can i do so? I am using PrimeNG

**HTML:**

```
  <p-autoComplete formControlName="location" field="name" [minLength]="1" placeholder="Location" [suggestions]="this.mccInstallationService.filteredInstallations"
                                     (completeMethod)="filterInstallations($event)"></p-autoComplete>
```

**Here is the UI:**

[image]

Comment: add [(ngModel)]="text" in HTML and assign your value to text in ts file so that you can handle it programmatically.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. Still renders blank

Comment: can you create a working plunker

Comment: need to know about your usecase what value you are willing to show and more plunker would be better.

Comment: I think you are looking for something like this - http://plnkr.co/edit/vKhkap?p=preview  It does the same thing what @HrishikeshKale was mentioning

Comment: yes, excellent! @Mkant